# Remove duplicate words from a sentence

Tags: code-golf, string

In this challenge, you will remove duplicate words from each **sentence**.

### Examples

```
Hello Hello, World!
Hello, World!

Code Code! Golf Code
Code! Golf Code

Hello  hello   World
Hello   World

Programming Golf Programming!
Programming Golf!
```

### Specification

- Input will be a string of ASCII characters.
- A sentence is defined as anything until the end of the string, a linefeed (`\n`), or punctuation (`.!?`).
- A word is defined as a sequence of `A-Za-z`.
- Words are case insensitive (`Hello` == `heLlO`).

- Only the first occurrence of a word in a sentence is kept.
- If a word is removed, the spaces *before* the removed word should be removed. (e.g. `A   A B` -> `A B`).

- As always [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: `a b a.` goes to what?

Comment: @ThomasKwa `a b.` because the ` a` is removed.

Comment: For `a__b_b_a`, do you get `a_b_a` (first `b` removed) or `a__b_a` (second `b` removed)?

Comment: @CamilStaps you would get `a__b__` because the repeated `b` is removed and the repeated `a` is removed

Comment: So you always leave the first occurrence and remove the later ones?

Comment: @CamilStaps Yes, the first occurrence is the one that is kept

Comment: Hang on, you edited that. Why `a__b__` and not `a__b` if the spaces before the last `a` and `b` are removed?

Comment: @CamilStaps If `_`s are supposed to represent whitespace then it would be `a__b`. Only whitespace before the removed word are removed

Comment: Ah, okay, yes, that's what I meant. Inline markdown code removes double spaces. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is this an acceptable input format? Each sentence is a separate input, and end of input is marked with a blank line

Comment: @LuisMendo no. The whole input will be in one string.

Comment: There are languages in which `\n` marks the end of _the_ (or _one_) input :-(

Comment: Are any other ASCII characters allowed? (other than letters)

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills All ASCII characters are allowed in the input. Only letters are considered words though

Comment: So `_` is a non-word ( which means I have to do some fixing )

Comment: Should we only remove spaces in front of a removed word, or other whitespace as well? (Like tabs, vertical tabs, form feeds...)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've specified "whitespace" but I guess it doesn't matter. You can remove other whitespace as long as you remove spaces.

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ you actually specified "spaces" which is why I asked to make sure that's intentional. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Vim, 27 bytes

```
:s/\v\c(<\a+>).{-}\zs\s+\1
```

Note that the 27 bytes is including a trailing carriage return at the end.

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=OiVzL1x2XGMoPFxhKz4pLnstfVx6c1xzK1wxCg&input=SGVsbG8gSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQpDb2RlIENvZGUhIEdvbGYgQ29kZQpIZWxsbyAgaGVsbG8gICBXb3JsZApQcm9ncmFtbWluZyBHb2xmIFByb2dyYW1taW5nIQ) Side note: This is a link to a different language I'm writing called "V". V is *mostly* backwards compatible with vim, so for all intents and purposes, it can count as a vim interpreter. I also added one byte `%` so that you can verify all test cases at once.

Explanation:

```
:s/\v                       "Substitute with the 'Magic flag' on. This magic flag allows us
                            "to shorten the regex by removing a lot of \ characters.
     \c(<\a+>)              "A case-insensitive word
              .{-}          "Any character (non-greedy)
                  \zs       "Start the selection. This means everything after this atom
                            "will be removed
                     \s+    "One or more whitespace characters,
                        \1  "Followed by the first word
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 98

*Note* while I found it myself, it's annoyingly similar to @Neil's, just with the additional logic to split the whole input string in sentences.

```js
s=>s.replace(/[^\n.!?]+/g,s=>s.replace(/ *([a-z]+)/ig,(r,w)=>k[w=w.toUpperCase()]?'':k[w]=r,k=[]))
```

**Test**

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/[^\n.!?]+/g,s=>s.replace(/ *([a-z]+)/ig,(r,w)=>k[w=w.toUpperCase()]?'':k[w]=r,k=[]))

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;[['Hello Hello, World!','Hello, World!']
,['Code Code! Golf Code','Code! Golf Code']
,['Hello  hello   World','Hello   World']
,['Programming Golf Programming!','Programming Golf!']]
.forEach(t=>{
  var i=t[0],k=t[1],r=f(i)
  console.log((r==k?'OK ':'KO ')+i+' -> '+r)
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), <s>66</s> 46 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
i`[a-z]+
·$0·
i` *(·[a-z]+·)(?<=\1[^.!?¶]+)|·
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=aWAgKig_PCFbYS16XSkoW2Etel0rKSg_IVthLXpdKSg_PD0oPzwhW2Etel0pXDEoPyFbYS16XSlbXi4hP8K2XSspCg&input=SGVsbG8gSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQpDb2RlIENvZGUhIEdvbGYgQ29kZQpIZWxsbyAgaGVsbG8gICBXb3JsZApQcm9ncmFtbWluZyBHb2xmIFByb2dyYW1taW5nIQ)

#### Explanation

Since only letters should be considered word characters (but regex treats digits and underscores as word characters, too), we need to make our own word boundaries. Since the input is guaranteed to contain only ASCII characters, I'm inserting `·` (outside of ASCII, but inside ISO 8859-1) around all words and remove them again with the duplicates. That saves 20 bytes over using lookarounds to implement generic word boundaries.

```
i`[a-z]+
·$0·
```

This matches every word and surrounds it in `·`.

```
i` *(·[a-z]+·)(?<=\1[^.!?¶]+)|·
```

This is two steps compressed into one. `<sp>*(·[a-z]+·)(?<=\1[^.!?¶]+)` matches a full word (ensured by including the `·` in the match), along with any spaces preceding it, *provided that* (as ensured by the lookbehind) we can find the same word somewhere earlier in the sentence. (The `¶` matches a linefeed.)

The other part is simply the `·`, which matches all artificial word boundaries that weren't matched as part of the first half. In either case, the match is simply removed from the string.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 326 bytes

Who needs regular expressions?

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#define a isalpha
#define c(x)*x&&!strchr(".?!\n",*x)
#define f(x)for(n=e;*x&&!a(*x);++x);
main(p,v,n,e,o,t)char**v,*p,*n,*e,*o,*t;{for(p=v[1];*p;p=e){f(p)for(e=p;c(e);){for(;a(*++e););f(n)if(c(n)){for(o=p,t=n;a(*o)&&(*o-65)%32==(*t-65)%32;o++,t++);if(a(*t))e=n;else memmove(e,t,strlen(t)+1);}}}puts(v[1]);}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 104 bytes

```perl6
{[~] .split(/<[.!?\n]>+/,:v).map(->$_,$s?{.comb(/.*?<:L>+/).unique(as=>{/<:L>+/;lc $/}).join~($s//'')})} # 104
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &code = {...}

say code "Hello Hello, World!
Code Code! Golf Code
Hello  hello   World
Programming Golf Programming!";
```

```
Hello, World!
Code! Golf Code
Hello   World
Programming Golf!
```

#### Explanation

```perl6
{
  [~]                         # join everything that follows:

  .split(/<[.!?\n]>+/,:v)     # split on boundaries, keeping them
  .map(                       # loop over sentence and boundary together
    -> $_, $s? {              # boundary is optional (at the end of the string)
      .comb(/.*?<:L>+/)       # grab the words along with leading non letters
      .unique(                # keep the unique ones by looking at …
        as => {/<:L>+/;lc $/} # only the word chars in lowercase
      )
      .join                   # join the sentence parts
      ~                       # join that with …
      ($s//'')                # the boundary characters or empty string 
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with -p option, 27 + 1 = 28 bytes

```perl
s/\A(\w+)[^.!?]*\K\s+\1//gi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP8ZRI6ZcWzM6Tk/RPlYrxjumWDvGUF8/PfP/f4/UnJx8BTCpoxCeX5STosjlnJ@SqgAiFBXc83PSwEwuiEKFDAgFUcoVUJSfXpSYm5uZlw5RiiSg@C@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, 57 bytes

**56 bytes code + 1 for `-p`**

```pl
s/[^.!?
]+/my%h;$&=~s~\s*([A-z]+)~!$h{lc$1}++&&$&~egr/eg
```

#### Usage:

```sh
perl -pe 's/[^.!?
]+/my%h;$&=~s~\s*([A-z]+)~!$h{lc$1}++&&$&~egr/eg' <<< 'Hello Hello, World!
Code Code! Golf Code
Hello  hello   World
Programming Golf Programming!
'
Hello, World!
Code! Golf Code
Hello   World
Programming Golf!
```

Might need to be +1, currently I'm assuming that there will only be spaces in the input, no tabs.

Comment: From a comment "All ASCII characters are allowed in the input. Only letters are considered words though" (I'll edit this into the challenge, I think)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Damn, ok I'll update to use `\s` instead... Still nowhere near your retina answer though!

Comment: Oh I see why you asked now. If we need to remove *whitespace* in front of words, then I need another byte as well. The question specifically says "spaces" though. I've asked for clarification.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I guess my comment wasn't really clear either! Thanks for your comments though!

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(?<=\b(\w+)\b[^.!?\n]*) +\1\b/ig,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY2xDoIwFEV3v6JMbQUhzooMDjq6OVhNCrQV8@gjxSh/X4UuxrDc93Jzcu5DvmRfuaZ7rizWyuvcD/luSJ3qQFaKZazY5qJk4h1zUV5uaVQIe11yEou1KLPGJJRyv1lUaHsElQIaphk9KgAkUybkjA7qiHL@T@2/i2SMiBwQ9PTOYEFG7uEE3Qx2cmicbNvGmqD7KcZ1/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 39 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ô┘ⁿ=3⌠↕ê║▌ßa⌡ô½â╖¬╥▓lå3Öîz╝╥'n┐←ûl₧'○0T
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=93d9fc3d33f41288badde161f593ab83b7aad2b26c8633998c7abcd2276ebf1b966c9e27093054&i=Hello++hello+++World%0AHello+Hello,+World%21%0ACode+Code%21+Golf+Code%0AProgramming+Golf+Programming%21&m=2)

I'm not sure if Stax's JS regex has the features to match up with Vim regex, but nested regex works!

### Explanation

```js
'!+".+?[\n!?]"{cV^{c:~\{:}m$"\s*"s+{i!*}Rc}Rd}RNd
'!+                                               append an ! to the string
   ".+?[\n!?]"                                    match anything(non-greedy),
                                                  followed by a sentence terminator
              {                              }R   replace each sentence with:
               c                                  copy it
                V^                                /[a-zA-Z]+/
                  {                       }R      for each regex word match:
                   c                              copy the word
                    :~                            toggle case
                      \                           zip the two
                       {:}m                       embed each pair in square brackets
                           $                      flatten
                            "\s*"s+               prepend \s*
                                                  Example for "wOrd":
                                                  "\s*[wW][Oo][rR][dD]"
                                   {   }R         replace each occurrence of word with:
                                    i!            index negated (1 if first)
                                      *           multiply with word
                                         c        copy
                                             d    delete the faulty replaced string
                                               Nd remove last !
```